# Counting dates that don't exist

Tags: r, date

I am working on a data frame that contains 2 columns as follows:

```
    time        frequency
  2014-01-06       13
  2014-01-07       30
  2014-01-09       56
```

My issue is that I am interested in counting the days of which frequency is 0. The data is pulled using RPostgreSQL/RSQLite so there is no datetime given unless there is a value (i.e. unless frequency is at least 1). If I was interested in counting these dates that don't actually exist in the data frame, is there an easy way to go about doing it? I.E. If we consider the date range 2014-01-01 to 20-14-01-10, I would want it to count 7

My only thought was to brute force create a separate dataframe with every date (note that this is 4+ years of dates which would be an immense undertaking) and then merging the two dataframes and counting the number of NA values. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution than what I've thought of.

Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to create the second dataset without doing it manually?

Comment: Here is my version `df2 <- data.frame(time= seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-10'), by='day')); setkey(setDT(df1), time)[df2, sum(is.na(frequency))]#[1] 7`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort by date and then look for gaps.

```
start <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
time <- as.Date(c("2014-01-06", "2014-01-07","2014-01-09"))
end <- as.Date("2014-01-10")

time <- sort(unique(time))

# Include start and end dates, so the missing dates are 1/1-1/5, 1/8, 1/10
d <- c(time[1]- start,
       diff(time) - 1,
       end - time[length(time)] )

d # [1] 5 0 1 1
sum(d) # 7 missing days
```

And now for which days are missing...

```
(gaps <- data.frame(gap_starts = c(start,time+1)[d>0],
                    gap_length = d[d>0]))
#   gap_starts gap_length
# 1 2014-01-01          5
# 2 2014-01-08          1
# 3 2014-01-10          1    

for (g in 1:nrow(gaps)){
  start=gaps$gap_starts[g]
  length=gaps$gap_length[g]
  for(i in start:(start+length-1)){
    print(as.Date(i, origin="1970-01-01"))
  }
}
# [1] "2014-01-01"
# [1] "2014-01-02"
# [1] "2014-01-03"
# [1] "2014-01-04"
# [1] "2014-01-05"
# [1] "2014-01-08"
# [1] "2014-01-10"
```

Comment: Nice idea. Probably OP is looking for `sum(diff(x$date)) + 1L`

Comment: Using the OP's dataset, `i1 <- diff(as.Date(unique(c('2014-01-01', df1$time, '2014-01-10'))));  sum(i1[i1>1])`

Comment: Good idea @akrun.  If you don't mind I'll use it, but I'll also put in a loop to tell which dates are missing.

Comment: when i use this code it returns: "error in rbind(deparse.level, ...): number of columns of arguments do not match"

Comment: @Andrew I couldn't reproduce your error, but I rewrote it without the data.frame syntax in the process of generating the missing dates.